# WordPress - How do I target child pages based on top-level parent name when writing function to create dynamic classes?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a custom theme for a client to use with the latest Wordpress release.  In this theme, the names of the pages (Contact, About, etc.) are wrapped in div#pageTitle.  This div is also assigned a class (such as "aboutTitle"), based on the section of the site.  The CSS is written to display an icon next to the name of the page, with a different icon assigned to each class.  The intended result is that all pages in a single section of the site should display an icon specifically for that section.  (Example: All "About" pages should have one icon, all "Articles" should have a different icon, etc.)

In this particular case, there is a top-level page called "About Us".  There are a handful of child pages under "About Us".  I would like "About Us" and all of it's child pages to display one particular icon, and I would like the class for displaying it dynamically written into the html based on a function written into functions.php.  (Naturally, other pages, sections, etc., will have their own associated icon.)

I wrote what I *thought* would work, and it does write in the appropriate class... except it writes that class for EVERY SINGLE PAGE IN THE SITE!  Can anyone explain what I have done incorrectly, and what corrections to make, to achieve the intended result?

The code I have included in functions.php is as follows:

```
// Identify the post title of the parent page
function parentPostTitle() {
/* is it a page */
if( is_page() ) { 
global $post;
    /* Get an array of Ancestors and Parents if they exist */
$parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
    /* Get the top Level page->ID count base 1, array base 0 so -1 */ 
$id = ($parents) ? $parents[count($parents)-1]: $post->ID;
/* Get the parent and set the $parentPostTitle with the page title (post_title) */
    $parent = get_page( $id );
$parentPostTitle = $parent->post_title;
}
}


// Enable dynamic PageTitle Classes
function dynamicPageTitleClass() {
    if (is_page("About Us") || ($parentPostTitle="About Us")) {
            echo ' class="aboutTitle"';
}  elseif (is_page("Contact Us")) {
            echo ' class="contactTitle"';
    } elseif (in_category("articles")) {
            echo ' class="articlesTitle"';
    } elseif (in_category("blogs")) {
            echo ' class="blogTitle"';
    } elseif (in_category("videos")) {
            echo ' class="videosTitle"';
    } else {
            echo ' class=""';
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for you time and assistance.

Comment: Please note: I DO know how to manually specify which pages to address.  I'd like to do this by targeting the children of the appropriate section so that the function dynamicPageTitleClass does not need manual updating every time the client decides to add a child page.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following revision of the code above was written by Justin Sangoi (an IRL acquaintance) and proved successful:

```
// Identify the post title of the parent page
function parentPostTitle(&$parentPostTitle) {
// function scope variables
$parentPostTitle = "";

// to be used for error messages.
$messages = "";

/* is it a page */
if( is_page() ) { 
    global $post;

    /* Get an array of Ancestors and Parents if they exist */
    $parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );

    /* Get the top Level page->ID count base 1, array base 0 so -1 */ 
    $id = ($parents) ? $parents[count($parents)-1]: $post->ID;

    // Check if $id is null or empty, at this point, an error needs to be thrown if so.
    if (!empty($id)) {
        /* Get the parent and set the $parentPostTitle with the page title (post_title) */
        $parent = get_page( $id );
        $parentPostTitle = $parent->post_title;
    }
    else {
        $messages .= "ID is null or empty. <br />";
    }
}
else {
    $messages .= "Not a page. <br />"; 
            /* Remove the above line when finished debugging child page switches, or all switches for posts and archives will bork. */
}

/*
  In the code calling this function, if messages is empty or null, the function succeeded.
  If not, the function had some sort of error message.  This can be logged or echoed to 
  the screen for debugging purposes.
*/
return $messages;
}


// Enable dynamic PageTitle Classes
function dynamicPageTitleClass() {
// function scope variables
$title = "";
$messages = "";

// Get the parentTitle from the other function using the pass by reference.
$messages = parentPostTitle($title);

// if no error message
if (empty($messages)) {
    if (is_page("About Us") || ($title=="About Us")) {
        echo ' class="aboutTitle"';
    } 
    elseif (is_page("Contact Us")) {
        echo ' class="contactTitle"';
    } 
    elseif (in_category("articles")) {
        echo ' class="articlesTitle"';
    } 
    elseif (in_category("blogs")) {
        echo ' class="blogTitle"';
    } 
    elseif (in_category("videos")) {
        echo ' class="videosTitle"';
    } 
    else {
        echo ' class=""';
    }
}
else {
    // deal with the errors here (maybe return them or log them)
            echo $messages;  
            /* Check targeted html for error message is visual output is incorrect. */
}
}
```

Make sure to read the comments, as this will not work as intended if you copy and paste without reading the comments and acting accordingly.

Also, I have since written more switches into the second function, and have found that it is very finicky about how the logic cascades.  If you write in a new switch and it doesn't work properly, try re-arranging the order of the switches.  So far, I've had to arrange it to first address is_search and is_404, then is_page (and its children), then category / tag and is_single.

I've posted this with Justin's permission, in case others may find it useful.  YMMV.

Comment: Depends on what I tried, surely due partly to my n00b status.  Example 1 - Using the code here [http://pastebin.com/4BX4WXNq] caused it to erroneously (*cough*) echo the "aboutTitle" class instead of the "authorTitle" class, resulting in incorrect icon display.  Rearranging it like this [http://pastebin.com/46CtxuB4] resulted in the correct classes and display.  I ran into a few others that yielded parse errors and fatal flaws, but haven't been able to duplicate them so I'm guessing they were easily attributable to laziness / inexperience on my own part.